# how to check if the user is typing a message

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I have been deploying a web based chat application which interacts with gtalk.  I was able to successfully make the app.  I want to add a new feature to this app.  I want to check if any gtalk user is typing before he sends a message i.e.  after the chat is invoked, is there any way to check if the gtalk user is typing; like the way gtalk displays "someone is typing" when someone is typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XEP-0085: Chat State Notifications is what you are looking for. You have to implement this in your client.
http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0085.html

Comment: Or even better: [Use the one that is already implemented in smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/ChatStateManager.html). :)

Answer (score 0):

Attach a key down listener which notifies the server each time the user presses a key. The server has to receive this and notify the other(s).

Although I don't have experience with gtalk. This is a generic solution. Don't how far it's possible with the libraries/frameworks you're using.

Comment: I want to know if the user on the other side is typing, not the user who is using the app

Comment: That's what I mean. You have to add a listener which will notify the server when the user is writting. Then the server notify the other.

Comment: Usually the client program has an option to allow the other side to see if you're typing.  You cannot force this on, as that would be a privacy violation. For example the Pidgin client has an option named "notify buddies that you are typing to them".

Comment: @JimGarrison : I want to know if the person on gtalk is typing, not the user using my app

Comment: That's my point. Unless gtalk provides an option to notify you the person is typing, and unless that option is enabled, you cannot know.